# Need jQuery help adding a class to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

My jquery skills are not excellent. What I usually do is take plugins then eventually figure out what I need to do.

What I am doing right now is that I have a slideshow script, and I want it so that when the next slide becomes active / visible, a function is run. What that function does is check for any ID that has a type of css (the type being set in an array), and then adding a class to it. The reason I'm doing it like this is because it needs to expand do different things depending on what the type is.

I have some general code, but I really don't know enough to figure out what I'm doing. Here is what I have thus far:

The function:

```
function doAnimate(index) {
      var item = $animations[index];

      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        var obj = item[i];
        if (obj['type'] = "css") {$(this).addClass('in');}
      };
    }
```

The Array:

```
  var $animations = [
      [{
        ID: "s5-01",
        type: "css"
      }],
      [{
        ID: "s5-02",
        type: "css"
      }],
      [{
        ID: "s5-03",
        type: "css"
      }],
      [{
        ID: "s5-04",
        type: "css"
      }],
      [{
        ID: "#5-05",
        type: "css"
      }]
    ];
```

This is the slideshow script and where it should run:

```
carousel.owlCarousel({
          ... cut stuff out that isn't important
          pagination:true,
          afterMove: function(elem) {
            doAnimate();
          }
        });
```

And here is how this particular one is set up in the HTML

```
        <div class="slide" id="slide-05">
          <img id="s5-01" src="img1.png" />
          <img id="s5-02" src="img2.png" />
          <img id="s5-03" src="img3.png" />
          <img id="s5-04" src="img4.png" />
          <img id="s5-05" src="img5.png" />
        </div>
```

So I have it like that, and the browser console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I am basically kind of lost, and in need of some assistance to get this working. I'm sure it is something basic that I just can't see, or perhaps I have it set up all wrong.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be  $('.animations:eq(index)') not $animations[index]
Since $animations is not a valid selector.
Check this http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to fix in order for this to work.

**JavaScript Array**

```
// Array
var $animations = [
  [{
    'id': "s5-01",
    'type': "css"
  }],
  [{
    'id': "s5-02",
    'type': "css"
  }],
  [{
    'id': "s5-03",
    'type': "css"
  }],
  [{
    'id': "s5-04",
    'type': "css"
  }],
  [{
    'id': "s5-05",
    'type': "css"
  }]
];
```

Then your function:

**JavaScript Function**

```
// Animate function
function doAnimate(index) {
   // Check array
   for (var i = 0, len = $animations.length; i < len; i++) {
       // If Array ID & Type match element ID
       if( $animations[i][0].id == index && 
           $animations[i][0].type == 'css' ) {
           // Add class
           $('img#'+index).addClass('in');
       }
    }
}
```

For this to work you must pass to `doAnimate()` the element **ID**, check my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfhbX/

Comment: "For this to work you must pass to doAnimate() the element ID" Of course you don't, that's totally absurd.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think you don't get what I mean, if he's evaluating every "active/visible" image, he must pass that image's ID/Class so he can check its properties and match it with values in array ;). I can't find anything "totally absurd" in my answer though, however you're welcome to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `$.each()`(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). I also simplified your array so that I can do this: `$animations[01].id` and get `s5-02` instead of `$animations[1][0].id` to get same value.

Array:

```
var $animations = [
    {
        'id': "s5-01",
        'type': "yyy"
    },
    {
        'id': "s5-02",
        'type': "css"
    },
    {
        'id': "s5-03",
        'type': "css"
    },
    {
        'id': "s5-04",
        'type': "css"
    },
    {
        'id': "s5-05",
        'type': "css"
    }    
]
```

Same HTML stuff. Here's the JavaScript:

```
function doAnimate(index) {
    var item = $animations[index];
    $.each($animations, function(idx, val) {

        // console.log(val); //logs the value of val to console at index `idx`

        //check the `id` val at index idx if equal to the passed item.id
        if (val.id === item.id && val.type === 'css') {            
            $("#"+item.id).addClass('in');
            return false;
        }

        //and just to test if not equal to `css`
        if (val.id === item.id && val.type !== 'css') {
            $("#"+item.id).addClass('yy');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Demo fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KpmNL/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
if (obj['type'] = "css") {$(this).addClass('in');}
```

There are two problems with that. The first is that your `if` condition uses `=` (assignment) rather than `==` or `===` (comparison). The second is that you're using `this`, but what `this` refers to isn't the element you want; you instead want to select based on the `id` property of `obj`, so:

```
if (obj['type'] === "css") {$('#' + obj.id).addClass('in');}
```

Then in this section of code:

```
carousel.owlCarousel({
    // cut stuff out that isn't important
    pagination:true,
    afterMove: function(elem) {
        doAnimate();
    }
});
```

That call to `doAnimate()` needs to be changed to pass an index for an element in your `$animations` array.

Comment: Can you show an example for your last comment to pass an index for an element the $animations array?